# How to write 2 crotchet (quarter note) triplets when they don't start on the down beat?

Tags: notation, rhythm, tuplet

I gave this question some thought but I may have worded it wrong so the best I can do is give an example. If you look in the second bar of the piece I am writing (below), there are three sets of quaver (eighth note) triplets.

[image]

The last two sets of triplets may be wrong and this is where I need help. The last two notes in this bar are actually crotchet triplets but I wasn't sure how to write them so I used quaver triplets and ties but not sure if this is the best way. Can someone please tell me if this is right, or correct me?

Comment: Just to be clear, what's the time signature for the excerpt? Looks like 4/4.

Comment: That’s absolutely spot on, except you want to put a crotchet (quarter note) in place of the tied quavers at the end of the second bar. This is clearer to read than what is in the answer below, as you can see where each beat is more easily.

Comment: @Todd, yes sorry I should have added that

Comment: @Bob Not sure what you mean. The last two tied quaver triplets are equal to 2 quaver triplets so how can I replace them with a quarter note which is equal to one beat. Would you mind doodling what you mean please?

Comment: Put the crotchet inside a triplet bracket, along with the preceding quaver.

Comment: @Bob Thanks. What you are saying sounds like what is in the answer below. Have I misunderstood you?

Comment: Hello, I posted an answer to show what I mean - it is half-way between your notation and the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd write it using "crotchet triplication"

[image: like this.]

if that better reflects the underlying accent/vibe structure.

Comment: I like this way. Seems like the right way. Was the way I wrote it wrong do you think or would both ways be acceptable?

Comment: This way implies a bit more of a ‘cut time’ feel to me— both the 4-grouped 8ths that start the excerpt and the 2-beat triplet. I prefer Bob’s unless the cut time is really what you’re going for here.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer uses good notation, and is perfectly legitimate. I find the use of a pair of quaver triplet groups easier to read than the crotchet triplet group though, as you can see where the beats lie. Either is fine, but this is certainly my preference:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You could just keep your tie structure but write the respective quavers as sextuplets on a single beam with a single 6 in the middle.

Comment: Nobody writes a two-beat sextuplet.